# Why index size greater than data size in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I noticed that in couple of InnoDB tables with a primary key, a unique key, one or two reference keys. The index length is considerably larger than the data length itself. The question is why?

The only thing I can think aloud is because InnoDB uses clustered indexes and stores table data along with primary key it is including data size in the calculation. I've not checked this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For InnoDB tables, the output of `SHOW TABLE STATUS` means the following:

- The `Data_length` field represents the size of all pages assigned to the clustered key (the `PRIMARY KEY` in SQL terms).
- The `Index_length` field represents the size of the sum of all paged assigned to all non-clustered keys (all `INDEX`, `UNIQUE`, etc. in SQL terms).
- The `Data_free` represents the size of all *extents* (not pages) which are allocated to the index but currently not used.

Now, aside from knowing how the space is accounted for, you should also keep in mind that every secondary (non-clustered) key will also contain all fields from the primary (clustered) key. If your `PRIMARY KEY` definition is particularly large, this could amount to a tremendous anount of space used in each secondary key.

If you provide your table schema(s) (using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) I could comment further.

Comment: Yes. The tables in question was quit large spanning 3 or more column composite primary keys. The moment I add a secondary key index length bumps up as you mentioned.